# Ionic Framework: Reorder list error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘getValues’ of null

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, typeerror

I'm doing a improved version of the Todo app from the tutorial, and I am getting an error when trying to reorder items from the list.

I think all is ok, but when I try to reorder items, Ionic gives this error, and reorder doesn't work:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValues' of nullReorderDrag.moveElement @ ionic.bundle.js:7429ReorderDrag.start @ ionic.bundle.js:7458ionic.views.ListView.ionic.views.View.inherit.startDrag @ ionic.bundle.js:7744ionic.views.ListView.ionic.views.View.inherit._handleDrag @ ionic.bundle.js:7804(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:7610triggerEvent @ ionic.bundle.js:811dragGesture @ ionic.bundle.js:1858detect @ ionic.bundle.js:1389bindDomOnTouch @ ionic.bundle.js:938

I'm testing it with Chrome in Mac OS X Yosemite, using "ionic serve". It doesn't work in Android or iOS neither.

I have created a Codepen with the app: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjjqPE

Here is the ion-list portion:

```
<ion-list show-delete="showDeleteTasks" show-reorder="true">
<ion-item class="item-remove-animate" ng-repeat="task in activeProject.tasks" item="task">
{{task.title}}
<ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="deleteTask($index)">
</ion-delete-button>
<ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reorder="reorderTask(task, $fromIndex, $toIndex)">
</ion-reorder-button>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And here is the reorderTask method from the JS file (it is called, but always with the same fromIndex and toIndex, so it does nothing):

```
$scope.reorderTask = function(task, fromIndex, toIndex) {
console.log("reorderTask llamado");
console.log("Task: " + task);
console.log("fromIndex: " + fromIndex + " - toIndex: " + toIndex);
$scope.activeProject.tasks.splice(fromIndex, 1);
console.log("reorderTask 1");
$scope.activeProject.tasks.splice(toIndex, 0, task);
console.log("reorderTask 2");
Projects.save($scope.projects);
console.log("reorderTask 3");
}
```

Am I doing anything incorrect? Or may it be an Ionic bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you change `<ion-content scroll="false">` to `true` your problem will be solved. :)

[Fix.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGbObE)